# ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb' - django + mysql

Tags: mysql, django, pymysql

This question concerns: django 1.5.1 with python 3.3 and mysql 5.6.12

Wanting to get Mysql running with Django. Had everything configured, even Database exists with user-pemissions. Got some error when trying syncdb:

```
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

There is obviously the Mysql-Lib for python missing. Downloaded the master-edition from petehunt/PyMySQL. Tried "python setup.py install" . Says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'constants'
```

Downloaded another version. A tarball from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL3/). Run "python setup.py install". Seems to work, tried to run the syncdb command "python manage.py syncdb". Still:

```
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Any suggestions what to do now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `pip install mysql-python`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am getting really angry here. Trying the thing running on Windows 7 x64. What happened now:
>> Tried to install it over pip says it needs vcvarsall.bat

Comment: Windows always gives you issues. That needs mingw compiler to install successfully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**mysqlclient** is the [recommended mysql driver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) for python 3

You can install it via pip:

> pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

Well I solve it. Downgraded to 2.7.x , so that i could use [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/?source=dlp%5d). Seems to me there should exist a big red warning for using django with python 3.x and Windows 7.